# Google image search in C#

Tags: c#

i found this code on github. when u type someting it will search on google and show first image to u in picturebox1 - now i want to add 3-4 other picture box and i want it to show other pictures as well (like second and third - not just the first one ). my problem is i can't understand how to do it.

```
try {
        this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        this._lblStatus.Text = "Searching...";
        this._lblStatus.Update();
        List<String> images_urls = t.SearchForImages (this._editImageText.Text.Trim());
        if (t.Error == null && images_urls.Count > 0) {
           //Show first image only
           foreach (String image_url in images_urls) {
              Bitmap bitmap = ImageUtil.LoadPicture(image_url);
              if (bitmap != null) { //sometime the server refuses getting the image directly
                 Image image = ImageUtil.ResizeImage(bitmap, pictureBox1, true);
                 pictureBox1.Image = image;
                 if (bitmap != null) bitmap.Dispose();
                 break;   //show only one image
```

What I have tried: i deleted the break; but it just keep searching and it never stop. i want it to be like other sites ( for ex: show 5-10 pic in every page ). what should i change ? what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Hi it would be good to provide a bit more information about your issue like where does that piece of code on GitHub comes from (i.e. url).
From my understanding you have a textbox where the user can type something (e.g. keywords) that leverage the Google search API to get you some pictures related to your keywords. You only get one picture and would to get more. May I suggest you to read that article on CodeProject which seems to be what you're looking for: https://www.codeproject.com/articles/11876/an-api-for-google-image-search

Comment: Also seems that Google image search API is deprecated and you can hence have a look at Custom Search here: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/overview
this includes a link towards the documentation of RESTful API (JSON)

Comment: thank u - i saw those two links - that project ( api for google image-search ) is not working anymore and i saw the second link before but i still have the problem :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides deleting the break from the loop, take the first 5 images only

```
       foreach (String image_url in images_urls.Take(5)) {
```

The above filter is done by a Linq method, of course you can change the number.
I guess you don't want to use pictureBox1 also for the other images: you can create the PictureBox controls with a `new` in the foreach loop and add them to the Controls collection

Comment: thank u so much. i was looking for that " .take(5) " thank u again.